# What is the use of autobind Telerik DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

The topic of my answer is pretty self explanatory.
I am having a Telerik MVC DropDownList like this:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Berater)
        .Name("Berater") //The name of the DropDownList is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
        .OptionLabel("-- Berater --")
        .DataTextField("Vorname") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the DropDownList as a text.
        .DataValueField("Id") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the DropDownList as a value.
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "target" })
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
            read.Action("GetUsers", "Api")
            .Data("filterProducts"); ; //Set the Action and Controller names.
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true); //If true, the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
        })
        .Enable(false)
        .AutoBind(false)
        .CascadeFrom("Studio")
    )
```

I asked my self, what is the purpose if the `AutoBind`? If I change it to true nothing happens... I can't find it somehwere in the documentation.

Comment: Note you can remove `.Name("Berater")` - all its doing is replacing the `name` and `id` attributes with what they already are. The use of `autobind` is explained in more detail [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid)

Comment: For what it's worth, autobind doesn't seem to work when using "CascadeFrom"